# I updated my maven-surefire-plugin from 2.20 to 3.1.2 and its giving me an error saying no test cases ran

Tags: java, maven, junit, plugins, cucumber-java

I am an automation engineer.

```
WARNING: Unexpected errornet.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: No JSON report file was found!at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonFiles(ReportParser.java:61)at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.generateReports(ReportBuilder.java:97)
```

I'm getting this error when I run [mvn clean test] with maven-surefire-plugin version 3.1.2 but works perfectly when I run with maven-surefire-plugin 2.20. Do I have to configure something in my project for it to work with version 3.1.2? also when I run with version 2.20, the target folder compiles a cucumber.json file but with 3.1.2 it doesn't compile a cucumber.json file. The reason I need to upgrade is because the surefire plugin 2.20 is using a log4j version that a vulnerability.

Below is my pom.xml and my test runner class. I want to know how to run mvn clean test without that error coming back

---

```
<pre><code>
  <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


<build>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>18</source>
                <target>18</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>utility.testRunnerClass</include>
                </includes>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

```
    <plugin>

        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.5</version>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>execution</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <projectName>Automations</projectName> <!-- Replace with project name -->
                    <outputDirectory>target/cucumber/</outputDirectory>
                    <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber</inputDirectory>
                    <jsonFiles> <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                        <param>**/*.json</param>
                    </jsonFiles> <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                    <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>

    </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>



</dependencies>
</code></pre>
```

---

```
<pre><code>
package utility;


    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            features = "src/test/java/features",
            glue = { "stepDefinitions", "utility" },
            tags = "@smoke",
            dryRun = false,
            publish = true,
            plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber/simple-reports.html",
            "json:target/cucumber/cucumber.json", "junit:target/cucumber/cucumber.xml"}
    )

public class testRunnerClass {

}
</code></pre>
```

I tried to see what other people did and add junit-jupiter-plugin but gave me back the same error. I just need some help making mvn clean test work with new surefire plugin and have all the correct reports in the target folder like simple reports and cucumber reports

Comment: I couldn't include all of my dependencies in the question but I am running the latest versions of guava, cucumber-reporting, maven-cucumber-reporting, selenium-java, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, webdrivermanager, junit 4.13.2, rest-assured, junit-jupiter-api 5.10.0-M1, junit-jupiter-engine 5.10.0-M1, joda-time, with Maven 3.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maven-surefire-plugin` automatically detect test engine based on your dependencies - but by default only **one** is used - Junit5 test framework has higer priority and it is used.

This behavior was changed between 2.x and 3.x version of surefire.

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#provider-selection

If you have mixed JUnit 4 and 5 tests in your projects you need to add junit-vintage-engine to your dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version><!-- junit 5 version used in project --></version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating the Maven Surefire Plugin configuration in your pom.xml as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        <properties>
            <configurationParameters>
                cucumber.publish.quiet=true
                cucumber.plugin=json:target/cucumber/cucumber.json
            </configurationParameters>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This configuration sets the cucumber.plugin property to generate the desired JSON report file in the target/cucumber directory.

- Also please remove the maven-cucumber-reporting plugin configuration since it is not necessary with the updated Surefire Plugin.
- Modify your testRunnerClass to remove the JSON plugin configuration since it will now be handled by the Surefire Plugin as below:

plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber/simple-reports.html", "junit:target/cucumber/cucumber.xml"}

By making these changes, you should be able to run mvn clean test with the updated Surefire Plugin version and generate the correct JSON report file in the target/cucumber directory, along with the simple reports and JUnit XML report.

Comment: After making the changes you suggested, the error log is now gone but my tests still do not run and no reports are created. I believe I need the Junit Vintage engine dependency because I'm using Junit 4 and 5 together.